# Custom flash component ApplicationDomain

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, fonts, components, applicationdomain

sFor some reason components aren't attached to the ApplicationDomain of their parent clip. I'm adding a custom component to the stage in flash and at runtime the the components parent ApplicationDomain is null. Also the ApplicationDomain of the swf with the component on it is not equal to the ApplicationDomain of the component. The reason I need it to be linked is for embedded fonts. What can I do to link the application domains?

Update:

Code in SWF frame 1:

```
import flash.system.ApplicationDomain;

if( myTextField.appDomain == ApplicationDomain.currentDomain )
{
    trace( "The domains are the same" );
}
else
{
    trace( "The domains are different" );
}
```

There is an instance of my component on the stage with an instance name of "myTextField".

Code in component:

```
public function get appDomain( ) : ApplicationDomain
{
    return ApplicationDomain.currentDomain;
}
```

The code on the stage returns "The domains are different" when I compile and run this.

Also "ApplicationDomain.currentDomain.parentDomain" is null in the component.

There is other code in the component, but nothing that would interfere with the appDomain getter.

Comment: I'm adding the components to the stage of the swf and compiling the swf. There is no custom loading in my code. This is all in a one frame swf.

Comment: Doing a swf dump on the swf searching for "doabc" gives:
<DoABC2 name=''>
</DoABC2>

Doing the same for "framelabel" gives no lines.

Code to come in question.

Comment: ApplicationDomain.currentDomain doesn't return a new instance of ApplicationDomain if I'm not mistaken. Live docs description: "[static] [read-only] Gets the current application domain in which your code is executing."

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17150/discussion-between-jordan-and-wvxvw)